# Configure rewriting url in localhost with EasyPHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, easyphp

I'm trying to configurate .htaccess to set rewriting URL in localhost, with EasyPHP, but all I get is 404 error.

My local website is C:\Projects\Test\, and in EasyPHP I created a new alias with "Test" name poiting to this location. So, to access this website, I type 127.0.0.1:8080/test in the browser.

The .htaccess file is addressed in the root of this website (C:\Projects\Test\ .htaccess). It's just an example, where everything typed redirects the user to "/user/inicial.php".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$ /user/inicial.php
</IfModule>
```

I've also follow these steps to configure apache to be able to run rewriting URLs:

- Changed httpd.conf file (addressed in C:\Programs\EasyPHP-12.1\conf_files) where:
- Uncomment "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" line;
- Change all "AllowOverride None" sentences to "AllowOverride All".

It's everything that I have done. If someone has more options to give me, I'll really appreciate.

Comment: Does `C:\Projects\Test\user\inicial.php` exist?

Comment: Hi Anthony! Yes, it does!

Comment: so if `http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/inicial.php` does NOT 404. change `RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$` to `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)$`

Comment: Hi Anthony! It didn't work too. In fact, the correct URL is http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/user/inicial.php